# Memoir class: how to change upper margin

Tags: memoir

I've been reading the documentation of the memoir class and trying to change the space between the top of the page and the header, but nothing I do seems to work. I've tried the commands \setulmargins and \setulmarginsandblock but every combination of inputs seems to only change the amount of space between the bottom of the text block and the bottom of the page.

This is not a problem with the a4paper size but with a5paper (which I'm using) the upper margin is excessively large, as shown in the image below.

Here, my preamble only contains:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a5paper, openany]{memoir}
\isopage
```

[image: Illustration showing the size of the upper margin]

Comment: After `\isopage` you have to use `\checkandfixthelayout`, as stated in `memoir` documentation.

Comment: @lacobus1983 Thank you, that worked! Would you mind adding that as an answer so I can give credit / mark as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `\isopage` you have to use `\checkandfixthelayout`, as stated in the memoir documentation.